# How to set the number of B frames in FFmpeg for H.265 encoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, h.265

I would like to re-encode an MPEG4 video into H.265 and want to manually control the number of B frames in the encoding. I tried the following command:

`ffmpeg -i test.avi -c:v libx265 -preset medium -x265-params crf=23 bframes=0 test_HEVC.mp4`

as suggested by the [x265 documentation](http://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/cli.html#slice-decision-options). However, I got the following error:

`[NULL @ 0x7f4e46f82e80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'bframes=0'
bframes=0: Invalid argument`

The command works fine without `bframes=0`, so I must be making a syntax error there. What would be the correct version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use `:` as a separator for `-x265-params` :

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -c:v libx265 -preset medium -x265-params crf=23:bframes=0 test_HEVC.mp4
```

Comment: If you prefer you can just use `-crf` option instead of using it via `-x265-params`. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265` for other [private options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#AVOptions).

Answer (score 0):

For ffmpeg you can use the -bf command to change the number of B frames between two frames. In your case you can use

```
-bf 0
```